# How can I lift an fclabels Lens to a Monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, lenses

I'm trying to update some old code using [fclabels](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fclabels), from [v0.4](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fclabels-0.4.0) to [v2.0](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fclabels-2.0) (lts-3.17), that lifts a `label`/`lens` to a monad. The old code is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
import Data.Record.Label
import Control.Monad (liftM, liftM2)

liftMLabel :: Monad m => a :-> b -> m a :-> m b
liftMLabel l = label (liftM $ get l) (liftM2 $ set l)
```

So the first thing I did was change `label` to `lens`, and `set` to `modify`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
import Data.Label
import Control.Monad (liftM, liftM2)

liftMLabel :: Monad m => a :-> b -> m a :-> m b
liftMLens l = lens (liftM $ get l) (liftM2 $ modify l)
```

This gave the following compiler error:

```
Expected type: (m b -> m b) -> m a -> m a
  Actual type: m (b -> b) -> m a -> m a
```

Which makes sense, giving how `liftM2` would treat each arg of the `lens` `modify` function.

The old fclabels used a setter function for creating a label, which accepts a simple value argument. The `modify` function, used for creating newer fclabels lenses, takes a function for modifying using the existing value, and I see why it too will operate on monadic arguments.

I'll need to perform some extra plumbing for the modify function, and I see that `ap` does something similar to what I want, but it's not clear to me what the best approach is in totality.

So what is a good way to deal with the `modify` function, so I can match the expected type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to write it all in one go in point-free style, why not just write it in long-hand?

```
liftMLens :: (Monad m) => a :-> b -> m a :-> m b
liftMLens l = lens (liftM $ get l) $ \f mx -> do
    x <- mx
    let v = get l x
    v' <- f $ return v
    return $ set l v' x
```

Of course you can then code-golf it if you really want to...

Comment: That's great, thanks. I had been looking for an overly generic (read impossible) way to do this.